# Verifying my proof of Liouville's theorem?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, proof-verification, power-series

Is my proof to  Liouville's Theorem, as formally discussed in $\text{Proposition (1.0)}$ correct ?.

> $\text{Proposition  (1.0)}$
>
> A bounded holomorphic function $f$ (i.e $|f(z)| \leq M$) on $C$ is constant.

$\text{Claim}$

One must formally show for $a_n=0$ for $n \leq 1$ by estimating

$$|a_n| = \, \left| \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\partial D(P,R) } \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta - P)^{n+1} } \, d \zeta \right| \leq \frac{1}{2 \pi} \frac{M}{R^{n+1}}2 \pi R$$

To verify the above claim, one must use the Cauchy's Inequalities and , formally developed in the proceeding $\text{Lemma}$.

$\text{Lemma (1.1) Power Series Theorem}$

Let $f$ be holomorphic on an open set $U$. Assume that $D(P,r) \subset U$. Then $f$ can be expanded to a power series $D(P,r)$ in $(1)$

$$f(z)= \sum a_n(z-P)^n, \qquad z \in D(p,r) \tag 1$$

where

$$a_n= \frac{f^{(n)}(P)}{n!} = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\partial D(P,r)} \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta - P)^{n+1} } \, d \zeta$$

$$\text{Cauchy's Estimate}:$$

Let $f$ be holomorphic on $\overline D(P,r) \subset U$ and let $M = \max_{z \in \overline{D(P,r)}} |f(z)|$ it follows in $(2)$

$$\vert f^{(n)}(P) \vert \leq \frac{n!M}{r^{n}} \tag 2$$

One let's $f$ be holomorphic on an open set $\Psi$, our $D(P,r)$ can be expanded as the following series in $(3)$

$$f(z)= \sum \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{\partial D(P,r)} \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta - P)^{n+1} } \, d \zeta(z-P)^{n}, \, \, \, \, \, \text{z} \in D(p,r) \tag 3$$

Letting $f$ be holomorphic on $\overline{D(P,r)} \subset \Psi$, one can apply the Cauchy Inequalities as formally recalled in $(2)$, one achives the recent developments

$$|a_n|= \left| \frac{f^{(n)}(P)}{n!} \right|  = \left| \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\partial D(P,R) } \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta - P)^{n+1} } \, d \zeta \right| \leq  \frac{n! \max_{z \in \overline{D(P,r)}} |f(z)|}{r^n}$$

From our prior developments one can observe for the integral: $|\int_{\partial D(P,R) } \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta - P)^{n+1} } d \zeta \vert $, the following occurs:

\begin{align}
& \left| \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\partial D(P,R) } \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta - P)^{n+1} } \, d \zeta \right| \leq \left| \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \right| \int_{\partial (D,r)} \left| \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta -p)^{n+1}} \right| \left| d  \zeta \right| \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\partial D(p,r)} \frac{|f(\zeta)|}{\left| (\zeta - P)^{n+1} \right|} \left| d \zeta \right| = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \frac{M}{R^{n+1}}2 \pi R
\end{align}

In summary, since $|a_{n}| \leq KR^{-n}$ for every $R$ each $n >0$ by letting $R \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is whether my proof is correct or not i'll have to reedit to make things clearer.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff : As this posting stands now, it appears that the question is in the very first line.

Comment: Well, you have to conclude your proof: since $|a_n|\leqslant K R^{-n}$ for every $R>0$, we conclude that $a_n=0$ for each $n>0$ by letting $R\to \infty$.

Comment: Also is there anything strange about my writing style, what is  $K R^{-n}$

Comment: It sounds correct. You are ready to prove the Cauchy integral theorem and formula, assuming $f'$ is continuous (otherwise it is hard).

Comment: I looked at how the cauchy Integral formula was proven and adapted this approach here.

Comment: You can try offering a bounty if you would like more help. Maybe the bounty could be for disproving your work?

Comment: @DrakeJohnson ive checked and the proof with the original in some lecture notes and a corresponding textbook I'm editing my earlier posts because they were not well written and doing such improves my skills in terms of exposition.